# nltk built-in (or easily obtainable) probabilistic parsing models?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

So I want to analyze the structure of fairly arbitrary English sentences with nltk. There seem to be lots of classes for doing this (eg PCFGs, `ProbabilisticProjectiveDependencyParser`s), but all require data to train on? Does NLTK come with data that can be used to train such parsers for arbitrary English (ie, I don't need exotic words, but basic English sentences should work).

[The demo for the PPDP](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/parse/projectivedependencyparser.html#projective_prob_parse_demo), for instance, seems to use a data set for Dutch. Further, this data sentence seems incomplete. It doesn't seem to be able to parse sentences with 'Ik' ('I' in Dutch according to google translate).

Comment: NLTK gives you access to lots of corpora you could use.  See [this info](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch02.html).

Comment: @BrenBarn I'm unsure which of the corpa would be appropriate for any particular parsing method? Eg, it seems its easy to get this wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056996/how-do-i-get-a-set-of-grammar-rules-from-penn-treebank-using-python-nltk

Comment: In fact, all the corpora you could use for training English parsers are available only from LDC with a restrictive license. This is why it's very hard if not impossible for open and free parsers to provide models based on them.

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin That is not true. The stanford parser comes with models, also here's a link for treebanks: https://code.google.com/p/uni-dep-tb/ and here's a link for parsers with models: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml#Methods

Comment: @Yasen sorry, I didn't clarify that I meant the consituency treebanks (referred in the question as PCFGs). Also, Stanford parser is a commercial product and that's why they are able to pay for the treebanks license (not to mention the ties between Stanford and LDC). (The free version of the Stanford Parser doesn't permit commercial use)

Comment: If you're willing to get your trees from outside NLTK, you'll have more options. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699646/how-to-get-logical-parts-of-a-sentence-with-java for a list of free (GPL and Apache 2.0 generally) parsers -- most of these parsers include parsing models. Once you have the parses, you can make NLTK trees out of them.

Comment: @Yasen btw, I've checked the Univerasl dependency bank and haven't found the actual files with dependencies in it. Do you have a direct link?

Comment: @VsevolodDyomkin Sorry for the sharp tongue, you're right about the Penn Treebank, LDC and Stanford. I've downloaded version 2.0 and there are dependencies in conll format in it: https://uni-dep-tb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/universal_treebanks_v2.0.tar.gz

Comment: @Yasen oh, I've found the dependencies in `ch/` dir, thanks. Unfortunately, no depednencies for English are available (I guess, this also has to do with the PTB restrictions). However, on the Stanford website you can find the dependencies extracted from the English Web Treebank (http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/data/EWT_DependencyGoldStandard_v0.3.tgz)